# Dialog <p:dialog> doesn't show using primefaces and facelets

Tags: jsf, dialog, facelets, primefaces

I'm facing a little problem with `Primefaces` and `Facelets`.

Here's the problem: I got a template file, that will be my base for all my screens.

```
            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.salvar}" action="#{managed.salvar}"
                update="cadastroMessages, #{formId}" type="image"
                image="../imagens/user_business_add_32.png" />

            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.excluir}" action="#{managed.excluir}"
                type="image" image="../imagens/user_business_close_32.png"
                update="cadastroMessages, #{formId}" />

            <p:commandButton value="#{msg.procurar}"
                onclick="#{modalConsulta}.show();" type="button" ajax="false" />

        </h:panelGrid>

        <ui:insert name="conteudo" />
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

The file that uses this template:

```
        <ui:param name="managed" value="#{managedAluno}" />
    <ui:param name="modalConsulta" value="modalConsultaAluno" />
    <ui:param name="formId" value="cadastroAlunoForm" />
    <ui:param name="header" value="#{msg.cadastroAlunos}" />

    <ui:define name="conteudo">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg.nome}" />
            <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{managedAluno.aluno.nome}" required="true" />

            <h:outputText value="#{msg.datanascimento}" />
            <p:calendar id="calendario" value="#{managedAluno.aluno.dataNascimento}" />

            <h:outputText value="#{msg.responsavel}" />
            <h:inputText id="resp" value="#{managedAluno.aluno.responsavel}" />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
```

On my index page, I got a `<p:menuitem>` that when clicked, will show a dialog for user `insert some data, using the code above.`

The dialog looks like this

`<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" modal="true">
    <ui:include src="/cadastro/cadastroAluno.xhtml" />
</p:dialog>`

Using ui:include, two html tags are inserted on my index page, and the worst, the dialog DOESN'T show up!

If i change `<ui:include>` for an h1 tag, works fine!
How can i get this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dialog boxes do not work inside panels nor panelGrid. It works inside layout and layoutUnits though. So put your dialog or confirmDialogs OUTSIDE panels or panelGrids.